# How to customize description box in flutter showcaseview package

Tags: flutter, showcaseview

I'm trying to implement the step by step widget highlighting using the [showcaseview: ^2.0.3 package](https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview)

The problem is it accepts only string in the description box but I need to add buttons to this box for moving to next/previous or to skip all. how could this be possible?
if it's not possible by showcaseview: ^2.0.3 is there any other way to achieve it?

[image: check is image to see what I need to achieve]